# asp.net validation control causing "random" error in javascript

Tags: asp.net, validation, internet-explorer-8

I have an `asp:FormView` on a control (in an ascx file) which is loaded onto a portal page along with some other controls.

I need to add validation to the form, but when I add any of the validation controls I get an apparently random error in the generated JavaScript when the page is loaded, and the validation doesn't fire when I need it to.

This is the code that I've got:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="FPITextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SomeNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FPITextBox4" Text="*"
    ErrorMessage="The number must be a whole number between 0 and 100,000" Type="Integer"
    MaximumValue="100000" MinimumValue="0" ToolTip="Must be between 0 and 100,000"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

This is the error I get when the page is loaded:

```
Message: Expected ';'
Line: 1159
Char: 60
Code: 0
```

When I look at line 1159 in the generated code it looks like this:

```
var ctl00_ctl00_main_col2_control_0_widgetcontrolX_3eba4918-7c7d-47aa-a089-
fd0ead0609fe_widgetcontrol_3eba4918-7c7d-47aa-a089-
fd0ead0609fe_FormView1_RangeValidator4 = document.all ?
document.all["ctl00_ctl00_main_col2_control_0_widgetcontrolX_3eba4918-7c7d-47aa-a089-
fd0ead0609fe_widgetcontrol_3eba4918-7c7d-47aa-a089-
fd0ead0609fe_FormView1_RangeValidator4"] :
document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_main_col2_control_0_widgetcontrolX_3eba4918-7c7d-
47aa-a089-fd0ead0609fe_widgetcontrol_3eba4918-7c7d-47aa-a089-
fd0ead0609fe_FormView1_RangeValidator4");
```

The code immediately above this is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById(
"ctl00_ctl00_main_col2_control_0_widgetcontrolX_3eba4918-7c7d
-47aa-a089-fd0ead0609fe_widgetcontrol_3eba4918-7c7d-47aa-a089-
fd0ead0609fe_FormView1_RangeValidator4"));
//]]>
</script>
```

The same code works when the control is just instantiated onto a test page all by itself.

It appears that the error only happens in IE 8. I've tested the same page in Firefox 3.6 and it all works as expected.

**Correction**

It appears that the validation is working. I had a `ValidationSummary` control set to show a message box and that wasn't appearing which led me to believe that the validation wasn't firing. When I changed that to `ShowSummary="true" ShowMessageBox="false"` the error message did appear and the data isn't saved.

So all it means now is that I've got a random script error that (at the moment) doesn't appear to be affecting the workings of the page.

However, I would still like to remove the error - just in case it's hiding something else.

Comment: the specified line seems to be ok. Are you using Internet Explorer? IE sometimes gives an incorrect line-number. You could try to debug with Microsofts Script Editor: http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/mt/archives/2006/01/howto_debug_jav.html

Comment: Since the error message indicates that a javascript line isn't terminated, the first thing I would try is removing the commas from 100,000.

Comment: @Pbirkoff - I am using IE, but if I add & remove other validation elements the line number moves around in line with the added/removed code. I'll try Firefox.

Comment: @Jamie - Good idea, but removing the comments had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you really found a bug in .Net client generation code - have a look at
http://haacked.com/archive/2006/07/14/ASP.NET2.0ClientValidationJavascriptBug.aspx

But no resolution from M$ - you'll have to generate IDs in a different way...

Comment: Interesting link. I don't think I've got any control ID's with "."'s in them, but I'll double check.

Comment: Just checked, no "."'s but the generated name is 160 characters long. Perhaps that's the issue. More investigation needed.

Comment: Yes, you do have one of forbidden characters there: "-".
Have a look at Note of Control.ID http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx
Use guid.ToString("n") if that's the only problem.

Peter Ivan

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this type of error results because of an error in one of my scripts, where there is a missing ;.  Do you have JS code in your page and is all of that correct, no missing semi-colons?

HTH.

Comment: That was my first thought, but the only change I've made is to add the `<asp:RangeValidator .../>` into the aspx. I've not added any new JavaScript to the page, which is what's really confusing me.